# Determining if a function satisfies the general wave eqation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, wave-equation

I am given the general wave equation:
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n \frac{\partial^n F(x,t)}{\partial x^n}=\sum_{l=1}^{\infty}b_l\frac{\partial^l F(x,t)}{\partial t^l}$$

I am supposed to show that $F(x,t)=Ae^{i(kx-\omega t)}$ solves this equation and then determine the type of equation that results when plugging in the function $F(x,t)$.

What I have got so far:

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n \frac{\partial^n Ae^{i(kx-\omega t)}}{\partial x^n}=\sum_{l=1}^{\infty}b_l\frac{\partial^l Ae^{i(kx-\omega t)}}{\partial t^l} \\ \iff \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n(ik)^nF(x,t)=\sum_{l=1}^{\infty}b_l (-i\omega )^lF(x,t)$$

There are three problems/questions that arise:

- Why does the right sum start at $l=1$ and not at $l=0$ like the left sum?
- In order for this equation to hold, $$a_n(ik)^n \stackrel{!}{=} b_l(-i \omega)^n$$
  but I would have to shift the index of the second sum right?
- Woul it be correct to say that the resulting equation is a system of linear equations?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Consider you have the term with $l=0$: $b_0F(x,t)$, but with $a_0F(x,t)$, you can redefine $a'_0=a_0-b_0$ and recover the sums with different start index.
- $\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n(ik)^nF(x,t)=\sum_{l=1}^{\infty}b_l (-i\omega )^lF(x,t)\implies\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n(ik)^n=\sum_{l=0}^{\infty}b_l (-i\omega )^l$

we cannont assume that the sums are always equal term by term. Consider, e.g. $f(x)=\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nx^n=e^x$ and $g(x)=\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}b_nx^n=e^{x^2}$ (starting at $n=0$, but we can redefine $a_0$!!)

Let's assume that the series are equal term by term, $\dfrac{(ik)^{2n}}{(2n)!}=\dfrac{(-i\omega)^{2n}}{n!};\dfrac{(ik)^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}=0\;\forall n$ That leads to $k=\omega=0$ as the only solution when clearly, $e^{ik}=e^{(-i\omega)^2}$ or $ik=-\omega^2+2\pi i m$

So, the equation to solve is $f(ik)=g(-i\omega)$ or $k=-if^{-1}(g(i\omega))$  to plug it into the solution...

Comment: Thank you and sorry for the late reply. I am not quite sure I understand the second point you made. Isn't the equation satisfied only if the sums are equal term by term? Or do you mean that the sum could turn out to have to same value even though not all the terms are equal?

Comment: I pretended to show with that example the contrary, that the equality of the sums term by term is in general a too restrictive condition to find a relation between $k$ and $\omega$. Only for some special cases the equality term by term brings such a relation.  In general, it has to be solved, so say, "in toto". If we are lucky, we have a nice expression for the functions associated with the coefficients of the equation and we can find the relation (as in my example).